# select dependientes con mysql en elementor (insertar en base de datos)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, elementor

En esta oportunidad quisiera su ayuda con esto, en verdad tengo días, revisando en google, y he probado de todo y no consigo la solución a este problema...

tengo un formulario en elementor pro, y tengo 3 select dependientes, estos se rellenan cada uno con base de datos de mysql (select estados) - (select municipio) - (select parroquias). bien esta parte la tengo hecha y lo inclui dentro del formulario de elementor con 3 shortcode.

el problema: de los 3 campos selects, el último de los select se envía null.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

marque los 3 select funcionando sin problemas...

Aqui muestro por consola que se envian los datos del los 3 select (los datos superiores los borre por seguridad, pero están alli también en sus inputs)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora el error que me muestra la consola

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 add_filter( 'elementor_pro/dynamic_tags/shortcode/should_escape', '__return_false' );

 add_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/new_record', function( $record, $ajax_handler ) {

$raw_fields = $record->get( 'fields' );
$fields = [];
foreach ( $raw_fields as $id => $field ) {
    $fields[ $id ] = $field['value'];

    $fields['estado'] = (isset($_POST['form_fields']['estado'])) ? $_POST['form_fields']['estado'] : '';
    $fields['municipio'] = (isset($_POST['form_fields']['municipio'])) ? $_POST['form_fields']['municipio'] : '';
    $fields['parroquia'] = (isset($_POST['form_fields']['parroquia'])) ? $_POST['form_fields']['parroquia'] : '';       
}

    global $wpdb;
    $output['success'] = $wpdb->insert('wp_organizacion', array( 'org' => $fields['org'], 'rif' => $fields['rif'], 'direccion' => $fields['direccion'], 'telefono' => $fields['telefono'], 'email' => $fields['email'], 'estado' => $fields['estado'], 'municipio' => $fields['municipio'], 'parroquia' => $fields['parraquia']));
    
$ajax_handler->add_response_data( true, $output );
```

}, 10, 2);

Este es el código para recibir los inputs e insertarlos en la base de datos... si elimino los 3 select inserta la base de datos sin problemas...

está modificado, ya que la propuesta de Triby funcionó al recuperarme 2 de los 3 valores del select. falta el ultimo por mostrar que sale null

P.D.: gracias de antemano el que se tome la molestia de ayudarme a resolver este problema. exitos a todos ustedes...

Comment: Desconozco si funcione, pero..., ¿intentaste obtener esos tres valores directamente de `$_POST`?

Comment: gracias por responder... Triby... oh atra vez ayudandome Triby, saludos amigo... disculpa mi torpeza, pero a pesar de hacer muchas cosas en elementor, hay dudas de como capturo esos datos por post... me explico, se como crear una varible la pregunta es donde la debo colocar, en mi functions.php?, en mi shortcode?, para saber que voy a obtener los valores y que no voy a estar buscando donde los encuentro... si me pueds dar un simple ejemplo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estoy suponiendo que los `shortcodes` no forman parte del formulario de *elementor* y por eso no obtienes los valores. No tengo idea si funcionará o no, pero puedes tratar de obtener los valores desde `$_POST`:

```
// Obtener el resto de campos
$raw_fields = $record->get( 'fields' );
$fields = [];
foreach ( $raw_fields as $id => $field ) {
    $fields[ $id ] = $field['value'];
}
// Tratar de obtener los otros 3 desde $_POST, o asignar cadena vacía
$fields['estado'] = (isset($_POST['estado'])) ? $_POST['estado'] : '';
$fields['municipio'] = (isset($_POST['municipio'])) ? $_POST['municipio'] : '';
$fields['parroquia'] = (isset($_POST['parroquia'])) ? $_POST['parroquia'] : '';
```

**Nota:** En caso de que los valores estén vacíos y, de acuerdo a la imagen de datos enviados, es probable que estés recibiendo un arreglo `form_fields` y debas cambiar a:

```
$fields['estado'] = (isset($_POST['form_fields']['estado'])) ? $_POST['form_fields']['estado'] : '';
$fields['municipio'] = (isset($_POST['form_fields']['municipio'])) ? $_POST['form_fields']['municipio'] : '';
$fields['parroquia'] = (isset($_POST['form_fields']['parroquia'])) ? $_POST['form_fields']['parroquia'] : '';
```

El único problema sería que, como mencioné anteriormente, si los campos no forman parte del formulario creado en *elementor*, sus valores se pongan automáticamente en `NULL` y habría que buscar otra forma.

Comment: si es correcto y no, me explico, los campos están dentro del formulario elementor si, pero no forman parte en el sentido de que los agregue con shortcode, ya que estos traen información de mysql respectivamente ya que son dependientes y no encuentro forma de que elementor haga esto por mi. tambien intento capturar los valores en un nuevo input hidden  de elementor pero no se como hacer para que obtenga el valor, o por jquery, ya que por ajax es un rollo porque solo lo procesa en la funcion callback, ya que es el unico sitio donde deja procesar para luego mostrar en donde quieras.

Comment: alli en donde pones tu codigo hice un vardump, y alli no llega los datos... lo que quiere decir que tengo que procesarlos antes de enviar alli... pero igual vuelvo a probar no me cuesta... gracias

Comment: Funcionoooo!!!!, solo parroquia no sale en null, pero ya con eso lo arreglo... gracias bro.... exitos.. P.D: la otra vez me ayudaste con lo del obtener la imagen de un audio para obtener el link lo recuerdas?... el servicio de panel lo resolvio por nosotros... exitos Triby.... gracias de nuevo

Comment: @FranciscoToro, excelente, me alegra que hayas podido resolverlo. Saludos.

Comment: ahora lo que no entiendo porque el post de parroquia llega null si es identico al post de municipio... son exactamente iguales...

Comment: @FranciscoToro, edita la pregunta para actualizar tu código y agregar una imagen donde se vean los _select_ en el inspector del navegador.

Comment: Solucionado: en el insert  el campo decia parraquia y no parroquia....

Comment: Una última pregunta Triby... Explicame porque si mis campos se llaman igual que los de elementor.... porque hubo que hacerse el cambio que hiciste?. porque elementor no lo reconocio, id ---> valor? en su get?... y lo otro, entonces como rendria que llamarse mis select para que elementor los pudiera reconocer directamente sin tener que recurrir a tu codigo? ya que veo que si cambio el nombre podria elementor tomarlo en su get...

Comment: Ya vi que editaste la pregunta, pero obtener los campos estado, municipio y parroquia debe estar fuera del ciclo, no tiene caso hacerlo dentro. En cuanto a tu duda, los campos no pertenecen propiamente al formulario de elementor, fueron agregados _"por fuera"_ con los `shortcodes`, por lo que no están registrados y elementor no busca esos valores como hace con el resto de campos que sí reconoce.

Comment: entendido, gracias por la explicación. Yo creia que no registraba sus propios campos sino que recorría los fields, los tomaba y los enviaba sin importar que no pertenecen a su propio form. ahora si entiendo esa parte... ya funciona todo correctamente... gracias  Triby nuevamente por tu gran ayuda y aporte... muchos éxitos para ti amigo...