# Campos dinamicos en elementor Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, elementor

Tengo un formulario en *WordPress* hecho con *Elementor*, le agregue un campo tipo `select` para agregar campos dinámicamente con jQuery.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El `select` funciona, el jQuery funciona, se ven los campos perfectamente en pantalla, pero para *Elementor* estos campos no existen.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que *elementor* me reconozca los campos creados?, dejo el código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen anterior muestro que si se envian los datos, solo necesito recuperar los valores e insertarlos en mysql con el siguiente codigo

```
add_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/new_record', function( $record, 
$ajax_handler ) {

$raw_fields = $record->get( 'fields' );
$fields = [];
foreach ( $raw_fields as $id => $field ) {
    $fields[ $id ] = $field['value'];
}

global $wpdb;
$output['success'] = $wpdb->insert('demo', array( 'name' => $fields['name'], 'email' => $fields['email'], 'message' => $fields['message']));

$ajax_handler->add_response_data( true, $output );

}, 10, 2);
```

en este enlace hay algo referente pero trato de implementarlo pero no se envian los datos. A ver si alguien me puede dar luces con esto, comparto el link donde se resolvió algo parecido

[select dependientes con mysql elementor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/507490/select-dependientes-con-mysql-en-elementor-insertar-en-base-de-datos)